# How to solve the following diophantine equation?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

$2x^3 + x + 8 = y^2$

[WolframAlpha tells me](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x%5E3%2Bx%2B8%3Dy%5E2+integer+solutions) that there are no integer solutions to this equation. But how could I deduce this from observation? If so, the next step, I guess, is proving that the $LHS$ can never be a perfect square.

Comment: Or   $x=8,y=12$ or $x=23,y=33$.

Comment: In fact, it looks like this should be equivalent to a Pell equation and have infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Note:  the WA link you provide refers to the equation $2x^3+x+8=y^2$.  Which equation did you mean?

Comment: **Edit:** indeed, the two equations provided weren't actually the same. The WA one was the right. I corrected it in the post. Apologies and thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 5):

Note:  The OP originally asked about the quadratic $2x^2+x+8=33$ but was later edited to ask about the cubic $2x^3+x+8$.  As this answer discusses, the quadratic has integer solutions (such as $(x,y)=(8,12)$) but the cubic does not.

The quadratic which appears in the post does have integer solutions (as pointed out in the comments) but the attached
WA link refers to the equation $2x^3+x+8=y^2$ which indeed has no integer solutions.

To see that the cubic equation has no integer solutions we work $\pmod 3$.  Since $n^3\equiv n\pmod 3$ for all $n$, we see that the LH is always $2\pmod 3$.  But $2$ isn't a quadratic residue $\pmod 3$ so we are done.

Comment: The $x,y$ pairs $8,12$ and $23,33$ do not appear to be solutions to $2x^3+x+8=y^2$

Comment: @poetasis   right, but the post originally concerned a different equation, namely $2x^2+x+8=y^2$.  The comments mostly concern that one.  And the pair $(x,y)=(8,12)$ is a solution for the quadratic version. Side note:  I wish people wouldn't edit posts to the point where comments and posted solutions become incomprehensible.